# Enabling anonymous access to a comm site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to create an anonymous sharing link for a  Sharepoint Online Communication site (the need is to have a Dropbox like site with link based access)
I tried to get a sharing link for the default Documents folder but I seem to understand it is not possible. 
I created a sub folder 'Docs' which I shared. Upon accessing the sharing link from an different Firefox container I can browse the Docs folder - but I can also go up a level and see the Documents folder (though no files are displayed). 
Is there any way to prevent users browsing an upper level or to share the efault Documents folder?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's by default that we cannot share entire document library to anonymous, and we cannot prevent users to navigate to the upper level of folder.

Users can access the upper level of folder, but they will never view the content that they don't have permission.

Comment: I thought as much, thank you very much. Is there a better way (within sharepoint of course) to anonymously share a bunch of documents?